# Creating a new global variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to create a list of variables that will be able to be called througout a script.  The variables will be coming from a SQL table.  Below is what I have so far.  I tried to set a single variable with no luck.  Any idea of what I could be missing?

```
Function GlobalVariables () {
    $ListQuery = "SELECT Top 1 SourceServer, SourceDBase, SourceObject, TargetServer, TargetDBase, TargetObject, TargetObject_IN FROM dbo.$ConfigTable WHERE OptionActive = 1"
    [array]$MovingList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ConfigServer -Database $ConfigDB -Query $ListQuery
    $MovingList | 
    New-Variable -Name DevServ $_.SourceSever  -Scope Global
}
Write-Output $DevServ
GlobalVariables
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct, you appear to be missing a foreach-object here:

```
$MovingList | 
    New-Variable -Name DevServ $_.SourceSever  -Scope Global
```

But generally, using Global variables is bad practice and I have to wonder if you wouldn't be better off putting all that into a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

`$DevServ` will not exist until *after* you call `GlobalVariables`. Meaning, these two lines:

```
Write-Output $DevServ
GlobalVariables
```

should be reversed:

```
GlobalVariables
Write-Output $DevServ
```